# I'm trying to drive a neopixel from my raspberry pi, but am unsure what the maxiumum length of my data cable would be

Tags: gpio

So I'm trying to run some neopixels off of my raspberry pi (which is possible through using the sound chip for a real time signal), my raspberry pi will be located some distance from the led strip, so I bought a 4 poled cable to drive power, and data through, however, when connecting the neopixels and my raspberry pi through said cable the LEDs don't work anymore.

My first instinct is that maybe the signal of the raspberry pi doesn't travel far enough, but I'm honestly not sure how to calculate that, so I'm looking for some help if possible.

The cable is 3 meters long, I'm using the GPIO 18 pin to send the signal and using the WS2812 LED strip (I'm pretty sure it takes VDD ± 0.5 v to drive those LEDs)

Comment: If you manage to get a WS2812 LED strip to run on a Pi (which Pi? which OS? using which software?) on a short cable **please let the rest of us know HOW** - then someone may be able to help you with length.

Comment: driving Neopixels with a microcontroller is not really a Raspberry Pi specific issue